# Accessing the session on socket requests with sails.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

When making a client request using io.socket such as;

```
io.socket.post('activity/subscribe')
```

There is no session information appended to the request object in sails causing my authentication policies to fail.

This is not a cross-domain request and the sails.sid cookie has been set. I'm using redis as a session store and for XHR requests the session is populated correctly.

My understanding is that sails handles the integration of sockets so that when a requests reached the app's routes it can be treated like any other request?

I've had a look at the answer in [Sails.js authorization for socket requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246681/sails-js-authorization-for-socket-requests) but that fails as req.socket.manager is not defined. 
Maybe that's for an older version of sails? Am in v0.11.0.

After sending the post request, I see the following in the console:

```
verbose: Receiving incoming message from Socket.io:  { method: 'post',
  headers: {},
  data: {},
  url: 'activity/subscribe' }
verbose: Interpreting socket.io message as virtual request to "post activity/subscribe"...
error: policy error here as no session..
```

Comment: This should definitely work!  Are there any messages in your console?

Comment: @sgress454 have update the question.

Comment: Any messages when you first start Sails?  Try `sails lift --silly`.  Also, I'm assuming you're using Redis for sessions as well?  Otherwise, make sure you close any browser tabs/windows pointing at the site before you lift the server, otherwise you'll end up with sockets connecting that don't point to a valid session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out eventually...

'activity/subscribe' - no good

'/activity/subscribe' - yay